# Object won't show in render. None of the suggested solves I've found have helped

Tags: rendering, objects, render-passes

I've tried to render my scene but there's an object that won't show up. I've checked the camera, I've checked the visibility, it isn't hidden and it's showing in the viewport. I feel like I've opened every setting and have achieved nothing.

I’m trying to render a book with a cover, flipping pages and stacks of pages. I have no idea how to fix the fact that the book cover doesn’t render. If I create a plane and select both the book cover and the plane and join them with Ctrl+J, the render contains a book cover but it doesn’t turn as it’s rigged to do so because it’s now linked to the plane and loses all the animated properties.

As soon as I unjoin them the book cover stops rendering and everything appears as you see it there, a book with binding, pages, but no cover. For the life of me I cannot figure out what’s going on.

There's a link to the file here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cfk05_-aZB1LpQat-6RGKB9IiDHZNffZ

Comment: Please include images and explanatory text in your questions. Users should not be expected to download a file to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your book armature has "Instances" in Face mode activated, that is causing the "invisible Object"

First change that to None.

second thing, your Cover has "Shadow Catcher " ON inside the visibility tab.
Uncheck that too.

[image]

Comment: This sorted it out. Thanks, a ton. You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

Your object is technically rendering. If you look very closely at the bottom of your rendered output, you can barely see a slight discoloration that represents the area where the light on the page's surface is broken up by the shadow going down the side of the book. It's very faint because the scene is extremely washed out. But the lighting is only part of the reason you weren't seeing anything.  Another issue is that, for some reason, your render result is very very small, dimension-wise, in relation to what it seems to me it would normally be, as if you set your output settings to make a postage stamp sized render. I checked those dimensions, though, and they seem normal. But the result of the intense lighting and the tiny output means that you aren't seeing most of the results of the render. I don't know how to fix this. You will probably be expected to open a new question if you want to try to get input about these other problems.

Comment: I have no idea how to fix it. If I create a plane and select both the book cover and the plane and join them with Ctrl+J, the render contains a book cover but it doesn’t turn as its rigged to because it’s now linked to the plane and loses all the animated properties. 

As soon as I unjoin them the book cover stops rendering and everything appears as you see it there. For the life of me I cannot figure out what’s going on.