# One of my objects won't show in my F12 or final render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, render-passes

I've tried to render my scene but there's an object that won't show up. I've checked the camera, I've checked the visibility, it isn't hidden and it's showing in the viewport. I feel like I've opened every setting and have achieved nothing.

I’m trying to render a book with a cover, flipping pages and stacks of pages. I have no idea how to fix the fact that the book cover doesn’t render. If I create a plane and select both the book cover and the plane and join them with Ctrl+J, the render contains a book cover but it doesn’t turn as it’s rigged to do so because it’s now linked to the plane and loses all the animated properties.

As soon as I unjoin them the book cover stops rendering and everything appears as you see it there, a book with binding, pages, but no cover. For the life of me I cannot figure out what’s going on.

Here is an image of what I want it to look like with the insufficient fix:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SjhNP9H_sebq0J0v8qn89SyKcTQb366g

Here is an image of what it comes out like:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=10uGX-7Sofb5DSG-eI_PHdyXur6zMTMQL

Here is an image of the settings in my project:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ARbn-s2rY2jcHrvfv_06y5C6My6HZHhG

Here is an optional link to my project:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cfk05_-aZB1LpQat-6RGKB9IiDHZNffZ

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215398/object-wont-show-in-render-none-of-the-suggested-solves-ive-found-have-helped

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: In the Properties panel > Object > Visibility, disable Shadow Catcher